# How to cluster customers by their purchases

Tags: clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have matrix with about 40 columns which are sales of specific products and about 15 000 rows. Each row is purchases of specific customer. The data consists of information about sales for 2 years period. 
I've tried K-means and HCA(linkage='ward') algorithms. But the results aren't good at all.
For visualizing I've used tSNE and for determining number of clusters Elbow Method and silhouette. 
But I cann't understand the results. Results of clustering have something like random nature. Silhouette shows strage result, images are below.
The elbow method:
[image]

K-Means with 6 clusters:
[image]

K-Means with 15 clusters:[image]

K-Means with 35 clusters:
[image]

HCA with 6 clusters:
[image]

HCA with 20 clusters:
[image]

HCA with 25 clusters:
[image]

What are the possible problems? And how to resolve them?

Comment: (upvoting just for fancy impressive pictures) Why didn't you consider 3-cluster solution?

Comment: Because one of clusters is too big. Also the biggest cluster has a lot of different objects which I can manualy split into different clusters.